# Expecting POST to Redirected to a GET - found POST

Tags: php, post, get

Can´t fix this error: "Expecting POST to Redirected to a GET - found POST".
I run this code with ngrok and XAMPP.

This is a part from following assignment: https://www.wa4e.com/assn/rps/.

Actually everything works OK, authorisation works great BUT in assignment's autograder there is this error:
"Checking to see if the POST redirected to a GET. Expecting POST to Redirected to a GET - found POST"

HTML part

```
<form method="POST">
   <label for="nam">User Name</label>
   <input type="text" name="who" id="nam"><br/>
   <label for="id_1723">Password</label>
   <input type="text" name="pass" id="id_1723"><br/>
   <input type="submit" value="Log In">
   <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
</form>
```

PHP part:

// Check to see if we have some POST data, if we do process it

```
if ( isset($_POST['who']) && isset($_POST['pass']) ) {
    if ( strlen($_POST['who']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['pass']) < 1 ) {
        $failure = "User name and password are required";
    } else {
        $check = hash('md5', $salt.$_POST['pass']);
        if ( $check == $stored_hash ) {

            // Redirect the browser to game.php
header("Location: https://c561-212-58-119-178.ngrok-free.app/rps/game.php?name=".urlencode($_POST['who']), true, 303);
            return;
        } else {
            $failure = "Incorrect password";
        }
    }
}
```

I've expected that additional parameters to header() as "...true, 303..." would help me, but nothing had chanchged :(

Comment: _Side note:_ md5/sha1 are **not** suitable for password hashing. The manual even warns about it: _"Warning
It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm."_ Use [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. Read how to use them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to terminate the code execution with `exit()` instead of `return`.  This ensures no further code execution:

```
if ( isset($_POST['who']) && isset($_POST['pass']) ) {
        if ( strlen($_POST['who']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['pass']) < 1 ) {
            $failure = "User name and password are required";
        } else {
            $check = hash('md5', $salt.$_POST['pass']);
            if ( $check == $stored_hash ) {
    
                // Redirect the browser to game.php
    header("Location: https://c561-212-58-119-178.ngrok-free.app/rps/game.php?name=".urlencode($_POST['who']), true, 303);
                exit();
            } else {
                $failure = "Incorrect password";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try enclose your code into below code**

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// your current code
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post only answers which fix the posters issue. Please refrain from posting assumptions "Did you try ..."   or "Try this or that"